# UITabBarController subclass never calls setViewControllers: or setViewControllers:animated:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, subclass, uistoryboard

I have a simple question: My custom `UITabBarController` subclass overrides both `setViewControllers:` and `setViewControllers:animated:`. When using my subclass in a storyboard, neither method is called. Why? How is the `viewControllers` property being set? Can I somehow hook into the moment when they are being set?

My code:

**MyTabBarController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@end
```

**MyTabBarController.m**

```
#import "MyTabBarController.m"

@implementation MyTabBarController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"I do get called, and at this point I have viewControllers");
}

- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
{
    NSLog(@"in setViewControllers:");
    [super setViewControllers:viewControllers];
}

- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"in setViewControllers:animated:");
    [super setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:animated];
}
@end
```

Note: I know that my subclass is being used because `viewDidLoad` gets called.

Comment: How did you instantiate the MyTabBarController with how many view controllers?

Comment: @visualication from a storyboard with 5 view controllers.

Comment: it could be, that the storyboard is suppressing the call. you could try setting up your tabbarcontroller programmatically.

Comment: @visualication Thank you. Of course doing it programmatically would work, but I was especially interested in the behavior in connection with storyboards.

Comment: there are a few differences. as for example with nib files you could set the text of a label with label.text in viewDidLoad. with storyboard this will not work, you have to use viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @Duncan, that the controllers are set by `initWithCoder` (or rather `loadView`).

Based on that assumption it's kind of obvious why the accessors aren't used: a subclass could override them (and maybe forget the call to `super` or assume the instance is fully initialized).

Although Apple missed to give advice you can find the recommendation of avoiding accessors during `init` in Google's [Obj-C Styleguide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml#Avoid_Accessors_During_init_and_dealloc) (and I believe I read that Stanford courses recommend that, too). And I heavily doubt that Apple would have written code to emit KVO-events in the initialisation phase.

So unless you need to manipulate the ViewControllers before they are added, why not go with the straight-forward solution?

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder 
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) 
    {
        [whateverYouWantToDoWithTheControllers:self.viewControllers];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
{
    [super setViewControllers:viewControllers];
    [whateverYouWantToDoWithTheControllers:viewControllers];
}

- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:animated];
    [whateverYouWantToDoWithTheControllers:viewControllers];
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcel, thank you very much! That is indeed the obvious solution! :) Great!

Answer (score 2):

From the docs it looks to me like setViewControllers:animated is a method intended for 3rd party developers to switch the list of view controllers installed in a a tab bar controller.

My guess is that when a view controller is loaded from an XIB or a storyboard, it sets itself up using initWithCoder rather than using the public interfaces. It is likely manipulating the instance variable that holds the array of view controllers manually.

Comment: That is my suspicion as well... It's a little unfortunate that it is bypassing both setters. I wonder if there's another way of hooking into the event of `viewControllers` being set... Maybe KVO :-(

Comment: KVO would probably work. I would try observing the property name first, and if that doesn't work, try observing the underscore-prefixed ivar. However, you are treading on thin ice here. Such an approach is going to be fragile. Future Apple iOS releases might do things differently, and then your code would stop working.